# How to verify if a prediction performance improvement is significant better?

Tags: predictive-models, model-evaluation

I have a model `M1` that achieved the predictive score (accuracy / AUC / F1 ...) of `s1` in the test dataset.

I developed a new model `M2` that achieved the predictive score of `s2` on the same testset. Suppose that `s2 > s1`.

Is there any test to confirm that `M2` is actually better than `M1`, or it is just the result of randomness in the models?

Comment: Is there any randomness involved in building your models or are they completely deterministic?

Comment: @user2974951randomness might come from data sampling as well - so the question here is that is there a kind of test that can say a model is actually better than other, like t-test in statistics.

Comment: No, this is not really done. If your models are random in nature then you could build multiple models and check their averages / variances, you could even use a test to check for significance, but this is dubious.

Answer (score 2):

A few possibilities come to mind.

If you have multiple datasets, you could use a Diebold-Mariano test. [The tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/diebold-mariano/info) contains information, as well as pointers to the original and a follow-up publication. The DM test is very commonly applied in the time series forecasting community, but there is nothing specifically "time-seriesey" about it.

If you have only a single dataset, then you could in principle bootstrap your model fits for both models and assess whether one improves on the other in (say) 95% of cases.

If you do this on the *same* test set in each replicate (only bootstrapping the training data), then all you can conclude is whether one model is better *on this particular test set*, so the bare minimum I would do would be to wrap the exercise in a cross-validation step. And even so, applying this machinery on a single dataset would be very prone to just making you very confident that an overfitting model is better than it actually is.

Answer (score 2):

[Dietterich (1998)](https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/articulo/dietterich1998.pdf) proposes a 5x2 cross validation followed by a t-test to identify better models. When comparing models across multiple datasets, [Demsar (2006)](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf) suggests the use of Wilcoxon Signed Rank test for comparing two models and Friedman test when comparing more than two models.